# Flutter: InkWell botton ontap not responding to clicks to submit form

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have this registration form which i want to sumbit when botton is pressed and register the user on firebase, i split the code file, so i have the screen_view codes in a separate file, the controller in a separate file and the Funtion to register the user on firebase in a different file named AuthRepo

Form Design Code

```
final signUpController = Get.put(SignUpController());


//Just pasted one field code for convinency sakes

            CustomTextFormField(
                              focusNode: _focusNodes[2],
                              prefix: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
                                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                  DefaultImages.userName,
                                  color: _focusNodes[2].hasFocus
                                      ? HexColor(AppTheme.primaryColorString!)
                                      : const Color(0xffA2A0A8),
                                  // color:  HexColor(AppTheme.secondaryColorString!)
                                ),
                              ),
                              hintText: "Email Address",
                              inputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                              textEditingController:
                                  signUpController.emailController.value,
                              capitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
                              limit: [
                                LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(25),
                                // FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                              ],
                            ),


//The InkWell Botton 

InkWell(
                              focusColor: Colors.transparent,
                              highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                              hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
                              splashColor: Colors.transparent,

                              onTap: () {
                                
                                signUpController.registeruser(
                                    signUpController.emailController.toString(),
                                    signUpController.pswdController.toString());

                              },
                         
                              child: customButton(
                                  HexColor(AppTheme.primaryColorString!),
                                  "Sign Up",
                                  HexColor(AppTheme.secondaryColorString!),
                                  context),
                            ),
```

// Signup Controller Codes

```
class SignUpController extends GetxController {
  static SignUpController get instance => Get.find();
  Rx<TextEditingController> fNameController = TextEditingController().obs;
  Rx<TextEditingController> lNameController = TextEditingController().obs;
  Rx<TextEditingController> emailController = TextEditingController().obs;
  Rx<TextEditingController> mobileController = TextEditingController().obs;
  Rx<TextEditingController> userNameController = TextEditingController().obs;
  Rx<TextEditingController> pswdController = TextEditingController().obs;
  Rx<TextEditingController> cPswdController = TextEditingController().obs;
  RxBool isVisible = false.obs;
  RxBool isAgree = false.obs;

  void registeruser(String email, String password) {
    AuthRepo.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        emailController.toString(), pswdController.toString());
  }
}
```

// AuthRepo Function to create register the user

```
//FUNC
  Future<String?> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password) async {
    try {
      await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      firebaseUser.value != null
          ? Get.offAll(() => const TabScreen())
          : Get.to(() => const WelcomeFirstScreen());
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      final ex = SignUpWithEmailAndPasswordFailure.code(e.code);
      return ex.message;
    } catch (_) {
      const ex = SignUpWithEmailAndPasswordFailure();
      return ex.message;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

when i press the botton nothing happens

Please what am i doing wrong?
How do i get it to work and submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

// Signup Controller Codes

You should make void registeruser function Future type and add async because the body of function use Future and also add 'await' at first of this line

```
AuthRepo.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
```

// AuthRepo Function to create register the user

Also avoid return null with dart in createUserWithEmailAndPassword fuction.

and final advice always debug the code (if you use vsCode just enter F5) for this kind of issues.

If it's work don't forget to vote ️.